# How to set an array of struct in the function param

Tags: solidity, web3j

this is the function :

```
  function setListObjects(ContractObject[] memory ContractObjects)public{
    delete objects;
    ContractObject memory newObject;
    for (uint i = 0; i < ContractObjects.length; i++) {
        newObject = ContractObject({
            id:objects.length+1,
            title:ContractObjects[i].title,
            description:ContractObjects[i].description
            });
        objects.push(newObject);
    }
}
```

but when i generate java class with web3j there is an error `Unsupported type encountered: tuple`
the problem that in my application i have to set all the array in one transaction . So what is the solution ?

Comment: Well if you have a problem on you web3 client side, then you should probably post your web3 client code.

Comment: the problem is when generating the client class java with web3j . The web3 client code is not generated yet .

Comment: I think web3j dont support this yet, giving struct as parameter was not possible before